# Data not showing on Handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I have the script below which extracts the data from MongoDB:

```
router.get("/visualizarinscritos/:id", eEmpresa, (req,res)=>{
result = []

Vaga.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then((vaga)=>{
    //console.log(Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vaga.candidatos))))
    
    Curriculo.find().then((curriculo)=>{
        if(curriculo){

            for(var r = 0; r < vaga.candidatos.length ; r++){
                for(var i = 0; i < curriculo.length; i++){
                    if(vaga.candidatos[r] == curriculo[i].usuario){
                        result.push(curriculo[r])
                    }
                }
            }
            res.render("empresa/viewcurriculos", {curriculo: result})
        }else{
            req.flash("error_msg", "Não há curriculos relacionados")
            res.redirect("/empresa/vagas")
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{
        req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao buscar usuários relacionados a vaga: "+err)
        res.redirect("/empresa/vagas")
    })
}).catch((err)=>{
    req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao carregar vaga: "+err)
    res.redirect("/empresa/vagas")
})})
```

I'm receiving the data as expected. I did a console.log and I'm getting it correctly:

```
[ {
_id: 60cabfad6494450bd0065877,
usuario: 60cabebfd90f8427c4840990,
experiencia: 'SAP Concur Reporting Analyst\r\n' +
  'SAP SE | 07/22/2019 - Current.\r\n' +
  'Support and develop reports on IBM Cognos\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Support team questions and handle issues\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Teach new colleagues\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Translate documents to Portuguese, English or Spanish.\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Create and support system automations\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Trilingual Service Desk Senior\r\n' +
  'HCL Technologies | 02/27/2019 – 07/19/2019\r\n' +
  'Teach news Service Desk Analyst\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Teach and remainder the team about process and new process or applications\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Answer the questions that the Analyst of Service Desk can ask\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Learn and participate of migrations of new applications\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Work on tickets that have a big priority\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Help key users solving problems and answering questions\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Verify the tickets that Service Desk done something and escalate it if necessary\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Bilingual Service Desk\r\n' +
  'HCL Technologies | 05/22/2017 – 02/27/2019\r\n' +
  'Support on applications that are homologated and used by the client\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Remote support on softwares\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Support on applications that are homologated and used by the client, O.S, networks and telecom\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'improve the Knowledge base\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Answer emails, calls and chats according the demands\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Manage tickets\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Internship – Maintenance of computers and networks\r\n' +
  'QI Escolas & Faculdades | 09/14/2016 - 05/18/2017\r\n' +
  'Administrative routines\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Servers maintenance\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Maintenance of cabling and switch\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Remote support on applications\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Local support on hardware and Telecom area.',
educacao: 'Associate in Analysis and Systems Development\r\n' +
  'Unisinos | 2017/2 - Current.\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'IT\r\n' +
  'QI Escolas & Faculdades | Completed at 2017',
certificacao: '>\r\n' +
  'ITIL\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '>\r\n' +
  'Active Directory\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '>\r\n' +
  'Exchange\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '>\r\n' +
  'Windows Server and OS\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '>\r\n' +
  'Network maintenance/management\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '>\r\n' +
  'Hardware',
idioma: 'Porguese\r\n\r\nEnglish\r\n\r\nSpanish\r\n\r\nLIBRAS',
habilidades: 'Java\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'SQL\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'HTML/CSS\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'JavaScript\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'EJS\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'NodeJS\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Android\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Angular\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'PHP\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'Cognos',
outros: 'Github: https://github.com/gabdonada\r\n\r\nFuncionou?',
__v: 0},undefined]
```

However, when trying to get the data using the Handlebars code below, the page is not showing values:

```
{{#each curriculo}}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4>{{curriculo.usuario.nome}}</h4>
        <h4>{{experiencia}}</h4>
        <small>Sobre: {{curriculo.experiencia}}</small><br>
        <a href="/empresa/curriculo/:{{curriculo._id}}"><button class="btn btn-success">Visualizar Curriculo</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
{{else}}
<h4>Não há curriculos registrados</h4>
{{/each}}
```

I tried by using and not using Each, but still not working. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this case is adding Async + Promise, as below. The res.render was redirecting to the page before the code completes. I also used `.lean()`:

```
Router.get("/visualizarinscritos/:id", eEmpresa, (req,res)=>{

var result = []
Vaga.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).lean().then((vaga)=>{
    
    Curriculo.find().lean().then( async (curriculos)=>{
        if(curriculos){

            const promises = []                
            for(const candidato of vaga.candidatos){
                for(const curriculo of curriculos ){
                    promises.push(
                        new Promise((resolve) => {
                            if(candidato == curriculo.usuario){
                                result.push(curriculo)
                            }
                            resolve(candidato)
                        })
                    )
                }
            }
           
            Promise.all(promises).then((resposta) => {
                console.log(result)
                console.log(result.usuario)
                res.render("empresa/viewcurriculos", {teste: result})
            })
           
        }else{
            req.flash("error_msg", "Não há curriculos relacionados")
            res.redirect("/empresa/vagas")
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{
        req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao buscar usuários relacionados a vaga: "+err)
        res.redirect("/empresa/vagas")
    })
}).catch((err)=>{
    req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao carregar vaga: "+err)
    res.redirect("/empresa/vagas")
})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Within an `#each` block, you need to use `this` to access the current array item. Therefore you should change your code to:

```
{{#each curriculo}}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4>{{this.usuario.nome}}</h4>
        <small>Sobre: {{this.experiencia}}</small><br>
        <a href="/empresa/curriculo/:{{this._id}}"><button class="btn btn-success">Visualizar Curriculo</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
{{else}}
<h4>Não há curriculos registrados</h4>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hi @selfagency that helped me, but has not totally fixed the issue. I implemented async + Promise and your solution, then worked fine